# How to parse XML Child Node

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have data in the following format:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/osu4w634lnoy2pw/2.xml

While trying to parse I want all the field elements also. I am able to get all the elements under table but not under field. Could somebody please help me?

My code is as follows:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@maploc);

        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/schema/table");

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            attribute1 = "";
            attribute2 = "";
            attribute3 = "";

            try
            {
                attribute1 = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
                attribute2 = node.SelectSingleNode("tabledefault").InnerText;
                attribute3 = node.SelectSingleNode("invoke").InnerText;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //Nothing
            }

            if (node.HasChildNodes)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode nodei in node.ChildNodes[i])
                    {
                        attribute4 = "";
                        attribute5 = "";
                        attribute6 = "";

                        try
                        {
                            attribute4 = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
                            attribute5 = node.SelectSingleNode("invoke").InnerText;
                            attribute6 = node.SelectSingleNode("dtype").InnerText;
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //Nothing
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is :

```
            for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode nodei in node.ChildNodes[i])
                {
```

You are iterating over the nodes that are the children of the current child (you are going one level too deep). This is because an `XmlNode` is an Enumerable over its Children.
A single `foreach` loop is needed :

```
            foreach (XmlNode nodei in node.ChildNodes)
            {
```